# Dynamically creating a player doesn't work in IE

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to use mediaelement.js as part of a gallery where images or videos swap in depending on which thumbnail you click. The URL is here: http://www.altny.com/portfolio/interactive.html

Here is my code (using jquery in a separate .js file)

```
// portfolio image/video swap
$("div.gallery-thumb a.gallery-swap").click(function() {
var newDesc = "<p>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</p>";
var newSource = $(this).attr("href");
if ($(this).attr("rel") == "image") {
    var newImage = "url(" + newSource + ")";
    $("section#project-image").empty().css("background-image",newImage);
    $("section#project-image").prepend(newDesc);
} else if ($(this).attr("rel") == "video") {
    // video handling
    $("section#project-image").css("background-image","none").empty().prepend("<video id=\"project-player\" src=\"" + newSource + "\" width=\"400\" height=\"270\"></video>");
    $("video#project-player").mediaelementplayer();
    $("div.mejs-container").css("margin","0 auto");
    $("section#project-image").append(newDesc);
}
return false;
});
```

this is working on Safari and Firefox, but doesn't work in IE8 (I don't have access to 7 or 9 right now). Am I using mediaelement.js improperly?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to put:

```
    $("video#project-player").mediaelementplayer();
```

below:

```
    $("section#project-image").append(newDesc);
```

Something like that is what I had to do to make IE7 work.

However, beyond that, I also have trouble with MediaElement.js in IE8 and I've seen other questions about that here as well.